# Emacs X toolkit support?

Tags: emacs

From what I understand, Emacs uses GTK as it's default X toolkit. Does Emacs support X toolkits other than GTK? For example, can I build Emacs to use Qt4 instead of GTK?

Comment: Only if someone wrote such version, which seems unlikely.  I'm not aware of *any* software which offers both a GTK and a Qt interface.

Comment: @goldilocks: If ever there was a program that'd do it, Emacs would be that program.  For some reason, though, some people are worried that such support would not fit in well due to Qt's C++-based API, even though the OS X port seems to fit in okay and that's in Objective C.  (If someone actually tried a port, we could even find out if they're right ...)

Comment: @SamB : Emacs is GPL'd, so anyone who *wants* to expand/port/whatever it in anyway is free to do so.  I did just notice that there's a vim-Qt in the works https://bitbucket.org/equalsraf/vim-qt/wiki/Home -- so in the spirit of one upmanship, Emacs should really do it too.  If you like C++, it would probably be a good way to learn about both it and Qt.  I imagine the "wouldn't fit in" line originates with someone who simply doesn't intend to ever do anything in C++, period, and what it really means is "I won't be doing any such thing, *because I do not fit in well with that*".

Comment: @goldilocks:  Yeah, "it wouldn't fit in" is not a very convincing claim in the absence of an actual port attempt.  I would certainly encourage any interested parties to give it a try, at least if they don't anticipate any difficulties with the [copyright assignment](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=gnulib.git;a=blob;f=doc/Copyright/conditions.text;hb=HEAD).  (I really do wish they'd be less insistent about that ...)

Comment: @SamB : You don't have to go along with all that if you want to *fork* a GPL'd project -- the copyright assignment issue applies to *official* GNU projects.  You would have to change/tweak the name; there are already [long running, *unofficial*, but perfectly legal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XEmacs) Emacs forks of that sort.  Have a look at section 5 of [GPL v3](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html), "Conveying Modified Source Versions".  Making it an *official* GNU project involves more hoops, but there's no need.

Comment: @goldilocks: Well, it doesn't seem like XEmacs has been getting much love lately.  However, I suppose it works well enough for something that follows the development more closely, like the Carbon port, or (*shudder*) AquaMacs ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`./configure --help` for GNU Emacs 24.3 informs me:

```
--with-x-toolkit=KIT    use an X toolkit (KIT one of: yes or gtk, gtk2,
                        gtk3, lucid or athena, motif, no)
```

So yes, you can use other toolkits, but Qt seems not to be not among them.

Comment: The lucid and athena toolkits are long obsolete, AFAIK. Motif is horrible (and is more a desktop environment than a toolkit really).

Comment: @vonbrand: The desktop environment is actually called [CDE](http://sourceforge.net/p/cdesktopenv/wiki/Home/).  And to be perfectly honest, I have Qt configured with `style=Motif` myself, and that at least looks more-or-less indistinguishable from lesstif.  (I haven't tried the real Motif yet, since it's only been open sourced a short while ago and Motif apps are kind of thin on the ground these days.)  Or did you mean that the API is horrible?